# Bing Maps WPF control not displaying polyline

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, bing-maps

I have a Bing Maps WPF control embedded in my WPF MVVM application (a pure ViewModel class is set as the DataContext for the whole view). To make the Bing Map conform to MVVM standards, I created a couple of Attached Properties so that I can show a route on the map. The main one of interest here is MapLocations - the app uses BingMaps REST API to get the list of coordinates for the RoutePath. Here is the XAML:

```
<bing:Map
    classes:BingMap.RouteLineLayer="{Binding ElementName=RouteLineLayer}"
    classes:BingMap.Locations="{Binding MapLocations}" 
    classes:BingMap.Origin="{Binding MapOrigin}" 
    classes:BingMap.Destination="{Binding MapDestination}" 
    CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource BingCredentialsForRoyalFoods}">
    <bing:MapLayer x:Name="RouteLineLayer" />
</bing:Map>`
```

Here is the MapLocations and RouteLineLayer attached property:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Locations", typeof (double[][]), typeof (BingMap), new PropertyMetadata(default(double[][]), LocationsChanged));

    private static void LocationsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var map = d as Map;

        if (map == null) return;

        map.Children.Clear();

        var routeLocations = e.NewValue as double[][];
        if (routeLocations == null) return;


        var locations = new LocationCollection();
        foreach (var routeLocation in routeLocations.Where(routeLocation => routeLocation.Length >= 2))
        {
            locations.Add(new Location(routeLocation[0], routeLocation[1]));
        }

        //Create a MapPolyline of the route and add it to the map
        var routeLine = new MapPolyline
        {
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            Locations = locations,
            StrokeThickness = 5,
            Width = 5
        };


        var routeLineLayer = GetRouteLineLayer(map);
        if (routeLineLayer == null)
        {
            routeLineLayer = new MapLayer();
            SetRouteLineLayer(map, routeLineLayer);
        }


        routeLineLayer.Children.Clear();
        routeLineLayer.Children.Add(routeLine);

        var rect = new LocationRect(routeLine.Locations[0], routeLine.Locations[routeLine.Locations.Count - 1]);
        map.SetView(rect);

    }

    public static void SetLocations(DependencyObject element, double[][] value)
    {
        element.SetValue(LocationsProperty, value);
    }

    public static double[][] GetLocations(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double[][]) element.GetValue(LocationsProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RouteLineLayerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RouteLineLayer", typeof (MapLayer), typeof (BingMap), new PropertyMetadata(default(MapLayer), MapLayerChanged));

    private static void MapLayerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var map = d as Map;
        if (map == null) return;

        if (!map.Children.Contains((MapLayer)e.NewValue))
            map.Children.Add((MapLayer)e.NewValue);
    }

    public static void SetRouteLineLayer(DependencyObject element, MapLayer value)
    {
        element.SetValue(RouteLineLayerProperty, value);
    }

    public static MapLayer GetRouteLineLayer(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (MapLayer) element.GetValue(RouteLineLayerProperty);
    }
```

I can see that the locations array is being populated correctly (I even tried hard coding some coordinates). No matter what, the Map doesnt show the line/route. It however does bound the map between the start and end points of the route correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the `LocationsChanged` handler you call `map.Children.Clear()`, but you never add any new child element, especially not the `routeLineLayer`.

Comment: @Clemens That was it!!! I was directly adding the MapPolyLine to the map before I changed it to use the new Map Layer for the routes (RouteLineLayer). I must have overlooked it when I changed the code and it was removing the Map Layer that actually had the router. Thanks a bunch! If you reply to the question, I can mark that as an answer so you can get the credit for it :)